# kafka performance test failed with OffsetOutOfRangeException

Tags: exception, apache-kafka

I downloaded kafka-dev repo from GitHub and intended to run performance test as per the [official page](http://kafka.apache.org/performance.html).

I built Kafka and ran the command in perf/README.md:

```
 ./sbt
  project perf
  package-all
```

Then I started zookeeper and kafka server and finally (in the perf directory):

```
 ./run-simulator.sh -kafkaServer=localhost -numTopic=10  -reportFile=report-html/data -time=15 -numConsumer=20 -numProducer=40 -xaxis=numTopic
```

But the test failed with `kafka.common.OffsetOutOfRangeException` and here's the error info:

```
Exception in thread "127.0.0.1-Consumer-10" kafka.common.OffsetOutOfRangeException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
at kafka.common.ErrorMapping$.maybeThrowException(ErrorMapping.scala:53)
at kafka.message.ByteBufferMessageSet.kafka$message$ByteBufferMessageSet$$deepIterator(ByteBufferMessageSet.scala:104)
at kafka.message.ByteBufferMessageSet.deepValidBytes(ByteBufferMessageSet.scala:90)
at kafka.message.ByteBufferMessageSet.validBytes(ByteBufferMessageSet.scala:75)
at kafka.javaapi.message.ByteBufferMessageSet.validBytes(ByteBufferMessageSet.scala:57)
at kafka.perf.consumer.SimplePerfConsumer.run(SimplePerfConsumer.java:78)
     ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this happening with storm?

Comment: I don't know. Why do you bring up storm?

Comment: I was having this issue when I was using storm, and the solution was to kill the topology and restart it.  If you don't know, chances are you're not using storm https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm (unless you're using someone else's packaged thing)

Comment: This typically happened when the consumer tries to fetch an offset which is not present or available, sorry to wake you up so late :) .. if you are using the 0.8 version, try to use the admin console script to first produce some messages and then consume at the consumer end